# Socket communication with iOS app [writen in swift]

Tags: php, ios, sockets, swift

I would like to make iOS application that would talk with my server, through sockets (script written in PHP).

I've been searching for days for some appropriate libraries and examples but I couldn't find any. Could someone propose some suggestions or sources that could be helpful, but just avoid telling me that I should rewrite the server in some other language :)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for cocoapods?
If you just type `socket` you'll get a lot of repos!

http://cocoapods.org/?q=socket

But if you don't want to include cocoapods in your project, searching for `swift socket` on github reveals there are plenty to choose from.

https://github.com/search?q=swift+socket

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement this from ground up by using raw sockets.

I think the best way to exchange data with your Server is by using the http protocol to access a web service (REST, SOAP, etc) your PHP application provides.

Try search terms like "ios rest php" "ios swift rest php" in Google and you will find many examples and tutorials.